# Why I get warning Can't convert one type to another?

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```cs
public TYPE GetObjBy<TYPE>() where TYPE : BaseConfiguration
{
  Type type = typeof(TYPE);

  if (type == typeof(MCConfiguration))
  {
    return (TYPE) new MCConfiguration(); <--- This line I get an error
  }

  return (TYPE) new BaseConfiguration(); <-- This line is OK
}
```

`MCConfiguration` extends from `BaseConfiguration`, but in one line I get an error but not in the other line. How is this possible?

**EDIT**

Using

```
ConfigurationParser par = new ConfigurationParser("");
MCConfiguration config = par.GetObjBy<MCConfiguration>();
```

**EDIT**

```
        public TYPE GetObjBy<TYPE>() where TYPE : BaseConfiguration, new()
        {
            Type type = typeof(TYPE);
            BaseConfiguration config;

            if (type == typeof(MCConfiguration))
            {
                config = new MCConfiguration();
            }
            else
            {
                config = default(TYPE);
            }

            return (TYPE)config;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you again converting `MCConfiguration` to `TYPE` as it is inheriting base class so no need of type casting again

Comment: Can you share how are you invoking the method?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar it is does not netter it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting this error because `GetObjBy<>` method can be used with any type derived from the `BaseConfiguration`:

```
class MappingSchemaTest : BaseConfiguration
{}

class MappingSchemaTestImpl : BaseConfiguration
{
    T GetObjBy<T>() where T : BaseConfiguration
    {
        return new MappingSchemaTestImpl();
    }

    void Use()
    {
        var t = GetObjBy<MappingSchemaTest>();
    }
}
```

Both `MappingSchemaTest` and `MappingSchemaTestImpl` are derived from the `BaseConfiguration`

However `return new MappingSchemaTestImpl();` can't be returned since `MappingSchemaTest` generic parametr is not the same as `MappingSchemaTestImpl`

PS add `new()` constraint on generic parameter and write like

```
    T GetObjBy<T>() where T : BaseConfiguration, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
```

PPS another option is not to return the generic but base class or interface like

```
    BaseConfiguration GetObjBy<T>() where T : BaseConfiguration
    {
        if (true)
                return new MCConfiguration();
        else
                return new MCConfiguration2();
    }
```

Comment: Two quesitons 1) Why I can return one type and can't another if they both extend the same base class `where T: BaseClass`? And 2) could you explain what does it means `new()` in this context?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko 1) generic parametrs are about something that is generic. It supposed to have something generic that is used for set of classes. However your implementation `return (TYPE) new MCConfiguration()` does not allow any other generic parameter that differs from the `MCConfiguration`. 2 new() adds `public parameterless constructor` constraint for generic parameter. [here is the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: Edited my question, could you please take a look. What do you think about it?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `config = default(TYPE)` is null for reference types (classes) so you are returning `null`. You have to change `GetObjBy` to return the `BaseConfiguration` or to use `new()` constraint and return `new T()`